# Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-digital-clock'. 'd:/React Project/firstapp/node_modules/react-digital-clock/lib/index

Tags: reactjs

when i try to use npm packages , after install it shows on dependency
but at the moment i import in my react project it gives me ab error
--> Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-digital-clock'. 'd:/React Project/firstapp/node_modules/react-digital-clock/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered errors of this type only in typescript. It means that you need to install types for this library.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/react-digital-clock
```

**UPD 1.0:** I checked the library on TS - it doesn't have a types declaration module. So you can mix your application with `.jsx` files.

You should create a new file: DigitalClock.jsx and set up your digital clock there. Here is an example (everything works): https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-ramanujan-m12n0b?file=/src/App.js

**UPD 2.0:** You can search types for any library [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/dt/search?search=)

Comment: try with your solution but , error in terminal -> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve